# How to update Ng-fullcalendar with angular 7

Tags: angular

I am not able to update full calendar when changing month or year.

I have tried

$("#ucCalendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
 $("#ucCalendar").fullCalendar('refetchEventSources',this.calendarEvents);

But nothing is working.

Comment: can you please elaborate your post?

Comment: Thanks, for asking. I resolved my issue. I was missed [(eventsModel)]="calendarEvents" property in template.

Comment: okay perfect. happy that you solved it yourself.